# Neural Network doesn't learn (Regression)

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I created code with NN that should work with california_housing dataset.
But it doesn't work.
I checked all in that code but I still got no solution. I'm stumped.
Maybe someone could help me with it?
Code:

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


data = sklearn.datasets.fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.data, data.target, test_size=0.25, random_state=13)


class MyDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.features = x
        self.target = y
        self.fv = self.features.values
        self.tv = self.target.values

        self.f_tensor = torch.tensor(self.fv, dtype=torch.float32)
        self.t_tensor = torch.tensor(self.tv, dtype=torch.float32).reshape(-1, 1)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.features)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.f_tensor[idx], self.t_tensor[idx]


train_dataset = MyDataset(X_train, y_train)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset,
                                           batch_size=128,
                                           shuffle=True, drop_last=True)

test_dataset = MyDataset(X_test, y_test)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset,
                                          batch_size=16,
                                          shuffle=False, drop_last=True)

class FeedForward(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dims, output_dim=1):
        super().__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dims[0])
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_dims[0])
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dims[0], hidden_dims[1])
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_dims[1])
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_dims[1], hidden_dims[2])
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_dims[2])
        self.dropout3 = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(hidden_dims[2], hidden_dims[3])
        self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_dims[3])
        self.dropout4 = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(hidden_dims[3], output_dim)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)

        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)

        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout3(x)

        x = self.fc4(x)
        x = self.bn4(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout4(x)

        x = self.fc5(x)

        return x

def train(model, optimizer, criterion, train_loader, device):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    correct = 0
    total = 0

    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        _, predicted = outputs.max(1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += predicted.eq(labels).sum().item()

    train_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader)
    train_acc = correct / total

    return train_loss, train_acc


def test(model, criterion, test_loader, device):
    model.eval()
    running_loss = 0.0
    correct = 0
    total = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, labels in test_loader:
            inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

            running_loss += loss.item()
            _, predicted = outputs.max(1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += predicted.eq(labels).sum().item()

    test_loss = running_loss / len(test_loader)
    test_acc = correct / total

    return test_loss, test_acc


def train_model(model, optimizer, criterion, train_loader, test_loader, device, num_epochs=10):
    train_losses = []
    train_accs = []
    test_losses = []
    test_accs = []

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        train_loss, train_acc = train(model, optimizer, criterion, train_loader, device)
        test_loss, test_acc = test(model, criterion, test_loader, device)

        train_losses.append(train_loss)
        train_accs.append(train_acc)
        test_losses.append(test_loss)
        test_accs.append(test_acc)

        print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}]: Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Train Acc: {train_acc:.4f}, "
              f"Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}, Test Acc: {test_acc:.4f}")

    return train_losses, train_accs, test_losses, test_accs


device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

hidden_dims = [100, 64, 32, 16]  

model = FeedForward(8, hidden_dims)
model = model.to(device)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

train_losses, train_accs, test_losses, test_accs = train_model(model, optimizer, criterion,
                                                               train_loader, test_loader, device)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(train_losses, label="Train Loss")
plt.plot(test_losses, label="Test Loss")
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(train_accs, label="Train Accuracy")
plt.plot(test_accs, label="Test Accuracy")
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

I was trying to change: numbers of layers, optimizers, optimizer params, number of epochs, learning rate and many more...

Comment: Code has to be in the question as text, not as external links.

Comment: Print the intermediate values. In the `def train`, try `print(outputs.flatten(), predicted.flatten(), labels.flatten())` and try to understand what's wrong. In fact, why do you compute accuracy? Your target variable is not some class that have discrete values. It's a real valued price

Comment: Now you need to clarify the "doesn't work" part, its again not clear to me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Alexey S. Larionov you are right. The problem in "computing accuracy". It is unsuitble in that case.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I founfd my mistake. I judged about nn working accordingly to   ansuitble metric.

Comment: Still you never clarified what the problem was, people had to guess...

Comment: I have been mistaken when I was trying to apply "Accuracy"  for avaluation of work of nn. It is not applicable  for regression. That was a foolish mistake:)  Actually my nn  was working  but I jumped to the wrong  conclusion due looking at "Accuracy"  that is not applicable for regression. That issue is resoved now. I just removed part of code that computes "Accuracy". I  applied MAE for evaluation of working my nn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your train loss was going down, so you're on the right tracks. The issue was mainly with the way validation metrics were computed.

The code was originally using `predicted.eq(labels)` which measures whether the values are *exactly* equal - but since this is a regression problem the values will not be exactly equal (they'd have to match down to the last decimal place). In short, the code was using a classification accuracy metric for a regression problem.

Since this is a regression problem, the task is to make the predictions as *close* as possible to the target, and the error here can be measured using the mean absolute error (MAE) which means 'how far off' the predictions are on average.

I've modified the code and it runs as expected. Scaling the data is usually required for nets; it helps stabilise training and improves convergence. I've added feature scaling to the code.

[image]

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = sklearn.datasets.fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True)

X_train_orig, X_test_orig, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.data, data.target, test_size=0.25, random_state=13)

#Fit scaler on training data, and scale the data
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train_orig).set_output(transform='pandas')
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train_orig)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test_orig)

class MyDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.features = x
        self.target = y
        self.fv = self.features.values
        self.tv = self.target.values

        self.f_tensor = torch.tensor(self.fv, dtype=torch.float32)
        self.t_tensor = torch.tensor(self.tv, dtype=torch.float32).reshape(-1, 1)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.features)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.f_tensor[idx], self.t_tensor[idx]


train_dataset = MyDataset(X_train, y_train)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset,
                                           batch_size=128,
                                           shuffle=True, drop_last=True)

test_dataset = MyDataset(X_test, y_test)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset,
                                          batch_size=16,
                                          shuffle=False, drop_last=True)

class FeedForward(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dims, output_dim=1):
        super().__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dims[0])
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_dims[0])
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dims[0], hidden_dims[1])
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_dims[1])
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_dims[1], hidden_dims[2])
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_dims[2])
        self.dropout3 = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(hidden_dims[2], hidden_dims[3])
        self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_dims[3])
        self.dropout4 = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(hidden_dims[3], output_dim)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)

        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)

        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout3(x)

        x = self.fc4(x)
        x = self.bn4(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout4(x)

        x = self.fc5(x)

        return x

def train(model, optimizer, criterion, train_loader, device):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    running_abs_error = 0

    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        predicted = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(predicted, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        running_abs_error += abs(predicted - labels).sum().item()

    train_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader)
    train_mae = running_abs_error / len(train_loader.dataset)

    return train_loss, train_mae


def test(model, criterion, test_loader, device):
    model.eval()
    running_loss = 0.0
    running_abs_error = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, labels in test_loader:
            inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

            predicted = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(predicted, labels)

            running_loss += loss.item()
            running_abs_error += abs(predicted - labels).sum().item()

    test_loss = running_loss / len(test_loader)
    test_mae = running_abs_error / len(test_loader.dataset)

    return test_loss, test_mae


def train_model(model, optimizer, criterion, train_loader, test_loader, device, num_epochs=10):
    train_losses = []
    train_mae_scores = []
    test_losses = []
    test_mae_scores = []

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        train_loss, train_mae = train(model, optimizer, criterion, train_loader, device)
        test_loss, test_mae = test(model, criterion, test_loader, device)

        train_losses.append(train_loss)
        train_mae_scores.append(train_mae)
        test_losses.append(test_loss)
        test_mae_scores.append(test_mae)

        print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}]: Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Train MAE: {train_mae:.4f}, "
              f"Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}, Test MAE: {test_mae:.4f}")

    return train_losses, train_mae_scores, test_losses, test_mae_scores


device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

hidden_dims = [100, 64, 32, 16]  

model = FeedForward(8, hidden_dims)
model = model.to(device)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

train_losses, train_mae_scores, test_losses, test_mae_scores = train_model(model, optimizer, criterion,
                                                                           train_loader, test_loader, device)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(train_losses, label="Train Loss")
plt.plot(test_losses, label="Test Loss")
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(train_mae_scores, label="Train MAE")
plt.plot(test_mae_scores, label="Test MAE")
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylabel("mean absolute error")
plt.legend()

plt.gcf().set_size_inches(8, 2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solution and explonation! I see that I have been mistaken with metrics...

Comment: @GregAvsyannikov if this answer worked for you, you can indicate it by clicking the check and accepting it. More info on accepting here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: My pleasure @GregAvsyannikov. It was almost there, I just made some changes to the validation metric.